# How To Run Script CLI using PHP, And Running Continously

Tags: php, websocket

When I a run php socket using CLI, the socket can run normally. When I run the script in php, the socket only runs for a while and then stops.

How do I run a CLI script in PHP so that the socket can run normally without stopping. Just like I run the script in the CLI.

CLI script To Running Socket:

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/php-cli /app/test1/backend/scripts/scedjule/echoTestWebSocket.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set `set_time_limit(0)` inside *echoTestWebSocket.php*, to avoid any timeout while executing the script.

Next call the script like

`nohup /usr/local/zend/bin/php-cli /app/test1/backend/scripts/scedjule/echoTestWebSocket.php &`

This will execute the script in the background and keeps it runing even if you exit the shell.

Usualy these kind of scripts are run as a deamon using `sytemctl` along with the apropriate configuration for the deamon, a unit file. For details read the man pages